# ¿Error al guardar un input dinámico?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Buenos Días... Nuevamente tengo dudas soy muy novato en esto de la programación tengo la siguiente cuestión, tengo un formulario donde estoy haciendo un input dinámico, pongo dentro de el un botón donde este genere los input, al momento de registrar se debe hacer en dos tablas diferentes pero me genera el siguiente error:

```
 Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\revista\rev\administrador\registro.php on line 27

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\revista\rev\administrador\registro.php on line 27
```

anexo los códigos que estoy utilizando;

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es" >
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../img/logo.png">
  <title>revista</title>
  <link href="../css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700,300italic,400italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var nexttema = 0;
    function AgregarCampos(){
      nexttema++;
      var num1 = '<tr><td id="rut'+nexttema+'"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="campo' + nexttema + '"&nbsp; name="articulo[]" placeholder="Articulo"/></td>';
      var num2 = '<td id="rut'+nexttema+'"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="campo' + nexttema + '"&nbsp; name="autor[]" placeholder="Autor del Articulo"/></td>';
      $(".datos2").append(num1 + num2);
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <section class="intro">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                <img src="../img/logo.png" class="img-responsive logo"><br><br>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
   </section>

   <section class="contenido">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <h3 class="titulo1">Subir una nueva revista</h3>
                <p class="descripcion">Para registrar una nueva revista, llena el siguiente formulario con todos los datos que se te pide,
                es necesario que o dejes ningun campo sin registrar.</p>
                <hr><br>
                <div class="col-lg-3"></div>
                <div class="col-lg-6" class="formulario_cuadro">
                    <form class="registro" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="registro.php" method="POST">
                        <fieldset>
                            <h2 class="texto_formulario">FORMULARIO DE REGISTRO</h2><br>
                            <label>Número o Volumen de la revista</label>
                            <input name="no_revista" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ejemplo: No. 1" required >
                            <label>Colaboradores</label>
                            <input name="colaboradores" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ejemplo: Juan Sanchez, Maria Luna, Manuel Torres,..." required>
                            <label>Fecha de publicación de la revista</label>
                            <input name="fecha_publicacion" type="date" class="form-control" required>
                            <h2 class="articulo">Artículos a registrar</h2>
                            <a href="#temas" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" onclick="AgregarCampos();">Selecciona para agregar un artículo</a><br>
                            <table class="datos2">
                                <br>
                            </table><br>
                            <label>Foto de portada de la revista</label>
                            <input class="form-control" name="imagen" type="file" required/><br>
                            <label>Archivo de la revista (Formato PDF)</label>
                            <input class="form-control" name="archivo" type="file" required/><br><br>
                            <input type="hidden" name="clave">
                            <div align="center">
                            <button type="submit" class="gb-thick-border">Enviar Información</button>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3"><a class="gb-thick-border" href="consultar_registros.php">Ver todas las revistas</a></div>        
            </div>
        </div>
   </section>

   <br><br><br>
    <div id="footerwrap">
        <div class="container">
            <h4>Todos los derechos recervados</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**registro.php**

```
<?php
include('funciones/funciones.php');
$obj = new revista_movimiento();

$no_revista =utf8_decode($_POST['no_revista']);
$colaboradores =utf8_decode($_POST['colaboradores']);
$fecha_publicacion =utf8_decode($_POST['fecha_publicacion']);

$imagen =$_FILES['imagen']['name']; 
$ruta = "imagenes/" . $_FILES['imagen']['name']; 
$resultado = @move_uploaded_file($_FILES["imagen"]["tmp_name"], $ruta); 

$archivo =$_FILES['archivo']['name']; 
$ruta = "archivos/" . $_FILES['archivo']['name']; 
$resultado = @move_uploaded_file($_FILES["archivo"]["tmp_name"], $ruta);

$obj->registro($no_revista, $colaboradores, $fecha_publicacion, $imagen, $archivo);


for ($i=0; $i < count($_POST['articulo']); $i++) { 

    extract($_POST);
    $articulo[$i]=utf8_decode($articulo[$i]);
    $autor[$i]=utf8_decode($autor[$i]);
    $clave=$clave;
}
$obj->registro1($articulo[$i], $autor[$i], $clave);

?>
```

**funciones.php**

```
public function registro($no_revista, $colaboradores, $fecha_publicacion, $imagen, $archivo){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO revista (no_revista, colaboradores, fecha_publicacion, imagen, archivo) 
                VALUES ('$no_revista', '$colaboradores', '$fecha_publicacion', '$imagen', '$archivo')";
        $consulta = $this->conecta()->query($sql);
        // echo '<script language="javascript">
        //      alert("Los datos se registraron con exito");
        //      window.location.href="index.php";
        //    </script>';
    }

    public function registro1($articulo, $autor, $clave){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO articulos (articulo, autor, clave)
                VALUES ('$articulo', '$autor', '$clave')";
        $consulta = $this->conecta()->query($sql);
        // echo '<script language="javascript">
        //      alert("Los datos se registraron con exito");
        //      window.location.href="index.php";
        //    </script>';
    }
```

No se porque me marca ese error, no se si lo este ejecutando bien en las funciones, necesito de su ayuda, se los agradeceria :) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error te sale porque intentas acceder a un array por clave/índice, la cual no existe.

Ejemplo:

```
$a = [1,2,3,4,5];

for ( $i = 0; $i < count( $a ); $i++ ) {
  // algún código
}

var_dump( $i ); // 5

// Salida var_dump( $a ): 
//array( 5 ) {

//  [ índice]=> valor //
//    [ 0 ]=> int( 1 ) 
//    [ 1 ]=> int( 2 ) 
//    [ 2 ]=> int( 3 ) 
//    [ 3 ]=> int( 4 ) 
//    [ 4 ]=> int( 5 ) 
//  } 

var_dump( $a[$i] ); // Notice: Undefined offset: 5 .....
```

El error dice que la clave/índice 5 no existe y si miras el array verás que no existe...

**Solución:**

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($_POST['articulo']); $i++) { 

    extract($_POST);
    $articulo[$i]=utf8_decode($articulo[$i]);
    $autor[$i]=utf8_decode($autor[$i]);
    $clave=$clave;

    // !!!!! meter aquí dentro del for-loop la función !!!!!!
    $obj->registro1($articulo[$i], $autor[$i], $clave);    
}
```

---

**Nota aparte:**

Estás vulnerable a [SQLi](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL)

Comment: Excelente, si estaba ejecutando mal el array, me ayudaste a resolver perfectamente mi duda y la explicación fantástica, muchas muchas gracias :) solo algo más @aldanux porque estoy vulnerable a SQLi?? para reforzar mis códigos

Comment: @R.Vivi - Me alegro.. pues estás vulnerable a SQLi porque no estás validando los datos al hacer el `INSERT` a tu base de datos. Deberías usar sentencias preparadas de [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) o [PDO](http://php.net/manual/es/pdo.prepared-statements.php)... saludos